# Java method not allowing a double?

Tags: java

Alright, so here's my two classes:

```
public void setArray(double anyValue){
    totalTax=0.0;
    total=0.0;
    for(int indexc=0; indexc < costArray.size(); indexc++){
       System.out.println("Enter the item name: ");
       String anyName = keybd.next();
       itemArray.add(anyName);
       System.out.println("Enter the item cost: ");
       double cost = Double.valueOf(keybd.next()).doubleValue();
       costArray.add(" " + cost);
       totalTax = totalTax + (cost * anyValue);
       total = total + cost;
    }
    totalTax = totalTax;
    total = total;
}
```

And I'm calling it from:

```
public TaxClass(int anyAmount)
{
    newList = new ArrayList<Input>(anyAmount);
}

    public void addItems(double anyTax){
    newList.setArray(anyTax);
    System.out.println("Item added!");
   }
```

I'm getting the error:cannot find symbol method setArray(double) ??

EDIT:

```
public void setArray(double anyValue){
 totalTax=0.0;
total=0.0;
for(int indexc=0; indexc < costArray.size(); indexc++){
   System.out.println("Enter the item name: ");
   String anyName = keybd.next();
   itemArray.add(anyName);
   System.out.println("Enter the item cost: ");
   double cost = Double.valueOf(keybd.next()).doubleValue();
   costArray.add(" " + cost);
   totalTax = totalTax + (cost * anyValue);
   total = total + cost;
}
totalTax = totalTax;
total = total;
}`
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is newList declared as? Btw. I only see two methods, not any classes.

Comment: BTW `total = total` doesn't do anything. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You do not have `newList` defined. Whatever class `setArray()` is defined at needs to be used to access `setarray()` from another class.

Example:-

```
Class Foo{

public void setArray(double anyValue){
//your code
}
}

Class Bar{

public void addItems(double anyTax){
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.setArray(anyTax);
    System.out.println("Item added!");
}

}
```

**UPDATE**

`newList` is defined as an ArrayList which implements the [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface. It does not have a method called setArray(). Take a look at my example above. In order to invoke a method from another class you will have to construct that object first.

Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Edited.  Yeah I do, in the constructor

Comment: Yes, but here is my setArray from the class it's calling, I'm editing it again, sorry.

Comment: @jtm22: Your second edit only shows the `setArray` method again, not the class it is a member of.

Comment: GOod catch, thanks.  But I don't understand..I posted a method directly showing you where setArray() is defined?

Comment: @jtm22 - I am confused. Your new `setArray()` is same as the old one. The **issue** here is you are calling `setArray()` on an ArrayList object which does not have that method. Which class has `setArray()` defined? I will update my post with the actual class names and then you can copy that code and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: @jtm22:  Which class is setArray() defined in?